# Properties.Settings.Default save to AppData but read from Program Files

Tags: c#, t-sql, triggers, settings

When I'm saving settings in context of process runas with specific login and password it's using his home folder (AppData) to store settings. But if I run program in context of the same user from T-SQL Trigger settings file form app_data is not used. There is config file which is used. It's placed in program files with executable. In this config are sections for WCF client settings.

I'm wonder why program doesn't try to read first config file. After manually putting some values to the user section in config when program is running from trigger - he will use them. But for save form single instance it store them in AppData. So after all, when running from trigger in default scenario he reads empty values.

BTW For running program in context of user from trigger I use EXECUTE AS USER = ... exec master..xp_cmdshell ... .

Best Regards

Comment: It's a *really* bad idea to be accessing *anything* outside of the same database from within a trigger. It's usually a far better plan to queue work (via e.g. service broker) and let the original transaction complete quickly.

Comment: For this moment in project it fits mine needs. But after lunch process fork itself and fast close. Maybe this is ugly solution but it works fast enough.

Comment: It works fast enough when everything is working fine. The issue comes if there are any problems accessing the external resources.

Comment: But thanks for comment I just googling for SQL Server Service Broker.

Comment: Should I look for solution with ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration ?

Comment: For first 2 Configuration FilePath is empty. For last one FilePath show path to .config file in application folder.

Configuration roamingConfig =             ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(               ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming);
            
Configuration localRoamingConfig =                 ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(                ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);

Configuration noneConfig =                 ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(                ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

Comment: When running from trigger I have ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal empty. Is something what I can do with that?